# REST API Call from VB ( ZOHO CREATOR )

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpwebrequest, zoho

Trying to make out this call

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-edit-records.html

I did tried everything but seems i need basic knowledge. Can anyone give me directions what is wrong with my code

```
Public Sub updateRecord(ByVal ht As Hashtable, ByVal criteriaField As String)

        Dim apiUrl As String = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/write/apikey=xxxx"
        Dim xmlStr As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim newvalue As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        newvalue.AppendLine("<newvalues>")
        xmlStr.Append("<ZohoCreator><applicationlist>")
        xmlStr.Append("<application name=copy-of-ebay-inventory><formlist><form name=Ebay_Inventory>")
        xmlStr.AppendLine("<update>")
        xmlStr.AppendLine("<criteria>")
        xmlStr.AppendLine("<field name='Ticket Number' compOperator='Equals' value='20573'></field>")
        xmlStr.AppendLine("</criteria>")
        newvalue.AppendLine("<field name='Found on site' value='1'></field>")
        newvalue.AppendLine("</newvalues>")
        xmlStr.Append(newvalue.ToString)
        xmlStr.AppendLine("</update>")
        xmlStr.AppendLine("</form></formlist></application></applicationlist></ZohoCreator>")

        Dim params As String = "XMLString=" + xmlStr.ToString

        Dim res As String = getResponseFromUrl(apiUrl, params)

    End Sub
Public Function getResponseFromUrl(ByVal url As String, ByVal params As String)
        Dim str As String = ""
        Try
            Dim webreq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
            webreq.Method = "POST"
            webreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(params)
            Dim dataStream As Stream = webreq.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            dataStream.Close()

            Dim res As WebResponse = webreq.GetResponse()
            Dim stream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
            Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(stream)
            str = streamReader.ReadToEnd
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Return str.ToString
    End Function
```

At the end of formating my xml looks like

[image: Sample]

But that is not that. 
Found a good example on ..

[LINK DEMO](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/cannot-see-my-post-about-asp-net#2266000002594784)

Reposnse

[image]

Comment: Wrap your attributes in quotes.

Comment: @N0Alias thank you for fast answer by attributes you mean to put quotes on ?
 `<field name='Ticket Number' compOperator='Equals' value='20573'></field>`

Comment: Perhaps that too, but I would look where the error message indicates...in element type "application".

Comment: @N0Alias You are right man. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all XML attribute values with a quote (single or double, although double is more common):

```
    xmlStr.Append("<application name=" & ControlChars.Quote & "copy-of-ebay-inventory" & ControlChars.Quote &
                  "><formlist><form name=" & ControlChars.Quote & "Ebay_Inventory" & ControlChars.Quote & ">")
```

Comment: Did u used this zoho ever ? Now is throwing me application name invalid

Comment: No, sorry.  My only three guesses to that exception are 1: That app name isn't associated with your key. 2: the dashes in the name should be treated differently.  3: They are expecting some sort of ID even though they list the attribute as name (or also expect an ID).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the *value* of the name attribute must be wrapped in quotes on the application node/element:

`xmlStr.Append("<application name='copy-of-ebay-inventory'><formlist><form name=Ebay_Inventory>")`

Note the `'` single-quotes around "copy-of-ebay-inventory"...